# Python - Incrementing a count producing unexpected results

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

In below code I expect `print('q.count' , q.count)` to be 2 as `count` is a varialble initialised once using `q = QueueFun()` and then incremented in the `read_queue` method, instead `print('q.count' , q.count)` prints 0. What is the correct method of sharing a counter between multiprocessesing Processes ?

Complete code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pool, Lock

class QueueFun():

    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
        self.lock = Lock()

    def write_queue(self, work_tasks, max_size):
        for i in range(0, max_size):
            print("Writing to queue")
            work_tasks.put(1)

    def read_queue(self, work_tasks, max_size):
        while self.count != max_size:
            self.lock.acquire()
            self.count += 1
            self.lock.release()
            print('self.count' , self.count)
            print('')
            print('Reading from queue')
            work_tasks.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = QueueFun()
    max_size = 1
    work_tasks = Queue()

    write_processes = []
    for i in range(0,2):
        write_processes.append(Process(target=q.write_queue,
                                 args=(work_tasks,max_size)))
    for p in write_processes:
        p.start()

    read_processes = []
    for i in range(0, 2):
        read_processes.append(Process(target=q.read_queue,
                                 args=(work_tasks,max_size)))
    for p in read_processes:
        p.start()

    for p in read_processes:
        p.join()
    for p in write_processes:
        p.join()

    print('q.count' , q.count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike threads, different processes have different address
spaces: they do not share memory with each other. Writing
to a variable in one process will not change an (unshared)
variable in another process.

In the original example, the count was 0 at the end, because
the main process never changed it (no matter what the other
spawned processes did).

Probably better to communicate between processes with Queue.
If it's really necessary, Value or Array could be used:

[17.2.1.5. Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing%20queue#sharing-state-between-processes)

> As mentioned above, when doing concurrent programming it is  usually
> best to avoid using shared state as far as possible.  This is
> particularly true when using multiple processes.
>
> However, if you really do need to use some shared data then
> multiprocessing provides a couple of ways of doing so.
>
> Shared memory Data can be stored in a shared memory map using Value or
> Array.
> ...
> These shared objects will be process and thread-safe.

[multiprocessing.Value](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing%20queue#multiprocessing.Value)

> Operations like += which involve a read and write are not atomic.

A slightly modified version of the question's code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Value

class QueueFun():
    def __init__(self):
        self.readCount = Value('i', 0)
        self.writeCount = Value('i', 0)
    
    def write_queue(self, work_tasks, MAX_SIZE):
        with self.writeCount.get_lock():
            if self.writeCount != MAX_SIZE:
                self.writeCount.value += 1
                work_tasks.put(1)
    
    def read_queue(self, work_tasks, MAX_SIZE):
        with self.readCount.get_lock():
            if self.readCount.value != MAX_SIZE:
                self.readCount.value += 1
                work_tasks.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = QueueFun()
    MAX_SIZE = 2
    work_tasks = Queue()
    
    write_processes = []
    for i in range(MAX_SIZE):
        write_processes.append(Process(target=q.write_queue,
                                args=(work_tasks,MAX_SIZE)))
    for p in write_processes: p.start()
    
    read_processes = []
    for i in range(MAX_SIZE):
        read_processes.append(Process(target=q.read_queue,
                                args=(work_tasks,MAX_SIZE)))
    for p in read_processes: p.start()
    
    for p in read_processes: p.join()
    for p in write_processes: p.join()
    
    print('q.writeCount.value' , q.writeCount.value)
    print('q.readCount.value' , q.readCount.value)
```

Note: printing to standard output from multiple processes,
can result in output getting mixed up (not synchronized).